# Vue.js jQuery render and binding HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

is it possible to output / render and bind and HTML String in Vue like code below?

```
...

methods: {
    funcA: function () {
        // some code here
    },
    funcB: function () {
        $('#example').html('<router-link to="/some/path"></router-link>')
    },
    funcC: function () {
        $('#example').html('<a href="" v-on:click="funcA()"></a>')
    }
}

...
```

thanks for response.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You want to use Vue, so don't resort to using jQuery when not necessary. And even if it were possible, it'd be `v-on:click="funcA"`. You assign the function, not whatever the execution of the function returns (unless the function returns a function).

Comment: then how it suppose to be if the funcB / funcC is called and generate a router-link / anchor dynamically?

Comment: That is impossible to say give the low amount of information of what you want to achieve.

Comment: you shouldnt be generating anything dynamically. what you want to do instead is update the state (e.g. `showRouterLink = true`), upon which the template will react by showing your `<router-link>`. this is called [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Comment: @connexo let say, i want to generate a router-link / anchor dynamically when the Vue is created or mounted or from any other trigger. what is the best approach should i used?

Comment: Depending on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Single `router-link`

In your `template`:

```
<router-link :to="dynamicPath" v-if="dynamicPath"></router-link>
```

Notice the double colon in `:to`.

In the `data()` function:

```
dynamicPath: null
```

In the `created()` / `mounted()` hook:

```
this.dynamicPath = "/what/ever"
```

### Multiple `router-link`s

If instead you want to generate a whole `list` of `router-link`s, this would be one approach:

In your `template`:

```
<router-link v-for="dynamicPath in dynamicPaths" :to="dynamicPath"></router-link>
```

In the `data()` function:

```
dynamicPaths: []
```

In the `created()` / `mounted()` hook:

```
this.dynamicPaths = [ "/what/ever", "/floats", "/your/boat" ]
```

Comment: ok, kinda get the solution. then if i have to loop the router-link on the vue script, how it goes?

Comment: I have done 1 year developing with Vue.js and had no need to access the DOM via jQuery once.

Comment: What do you mean, loop? Is this still the same question?

Comment: oh well, i just start my vue experience and think that vue can combine smoothly with jquery

Comment: the loop is another case. like looping via v-for in the html element, but loop in the vue script instead

Comment: Why would you not want to use `v-for` in the template? You need to stop thinking in DOM, and start thinking in application **state** and data. Inserted a code example for dynamically creating a list of router links.

Comment: i dont have any code, just in case if i need to loop the dynamicPaths (multiple) but just execute from methods, not on the directive.